Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{\mu}{n}\right)^{k}\left(1-\frac{\mu}{n}\right)^{n-k}=\frac{\mu^k}{e^\mu\cdot{k!}}$
The problem is to prove the following equality:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{\mu}{n}\right)^{k}\left(1-\frac{\mu}{n}\right)^{n-k}=\frac{\mu^k}{e^\mu\cdot{k!}}$$
This is what I have gotten so far. Setting our original expression for the limit equal to $L$, we have
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{\mu}{n}\right)^{k}\left(1-\frac{\mu}{n}\right)^{n-k}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\left(\frac{\mu}{n}\right)^{k}\frac{\left(1-\frac{\mu}{n}\right)^n}{\left(1-\frac{\mu}{n}\right)^k}$$
$$=\frac{1}{k!}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\left(\frac{\frac{\mu}{n}}{1-\frac{\mu}{n}}\right)^k\left(1-\frac{\mu}{n}\right)^n$$
$$=\frac{1}{k!}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\left(\frac{1}{\frac{n}{\mu}-1}\right)^k\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{\mu}{n}\right)^n$$
Then, using the limit definition of Euler's number
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$$
It's pretty easy to show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{\mu}{n}\right)^n=e^{-\mu}$$
Bringing that out front, we now have
$$=\frac{1}{e^\mu\cdot{k!}}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\left(\frac{1}{\frac{n}{\mu}-1}\right)^k$$
$$=\frac{1}{e^\mu\cdot{k!}}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n)(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{\left(\frac{n}{\mu}-1\right)^k}$$
But from there, I'm not sure how to go about solving that limit. Assuming I've done the rest of this correctly, that would mean that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n)(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{\left(\frac{n}{\mu}-1\right)^k}=\mu^k$$
But again, I'm not sure how to show that. How would you evaluate that final limit? Or is there another way of writing it that makes it easier to find?

If you take logarithms, using Striling formula, you cound even go beyonf the limit and obtain $$\frac{\mu^k}{e^\mu,{k!}}\Big(1+\frac{-k^2+2 k \mu +k-\mu ^2}{2
n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\Big)$$

Note that
$$\frac{n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)}{\left(\frac{n}{\mu}-1\right)^k}=\mu^k\frac{n^k+(\text{lower degree terms})}{n^k+(\text{lower degree terms})}.$$
